# Как правильно реализовать логику работы в html+jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Доброго времени суток!

Задача: есть фотография бланка. Надо реализовать такую схему:

- бланк разбит на категории, для каждой категории есть HTML-вариант странички
- по нажатию на категорию на изображении ( фотографии бланка ) должен всплывать фрэйм с HTML-содержимым этой категории ( т.е. выглядит как эффект увеличения части изображения )

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать? Куда глядеть и что почитать по этой теме?

P.S. Может вопрос глупый, но у меня профиль С++ и системное программирование, а тут вот всплыла такая задача :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как вариант можно использовать <map>, например:

```
<img src="images/navigate.png" width="640" height="30" alt="Бланк" usemap="#Navigation">  <map name="Navigation">
  <area id="link1" shape="rect" coords="10,10,100,50" href="link1.html">
  <area id="link2" shape="rect" coords="10,55,100,105" href="link2.html">
  <area id="link3" shape="rect" coords="10,110,100,155" href="link3.html">
</map>
```

А для динамической загрузки контента, например jQuery:

```
$(area).click(function(){
  $('#result').load($(this).attr('id')+'.html');
  $('#result').show();
  return false;
});
```

Немного поясню:
return false; - чтобы не отрабатывал стандартный клик, и вас не перекидывало по ссылке или можно использовать nohref.
$(this).attr('id') - лучше использовать тег id и другие, т.к. href в IE отрабатывается не правильно.

`#result` - можно с помощью css разместить там где Вам удобно, над рисунком или сбоку, это уже отдельный вопрос. Или вместо него можно использовать jQuery UI Dialog.

Comment: Если вдруг непонятно, выкладывайте вашу картинку и пару кусков хтмл, сверстаем примерчик.

Comment: ncmarinescience.com - вот другой вариант решения. Там дива с картой имеет относительное позиционирование, а ссылки внутри прорисованы с абсолютным позиционированием, тоже неплохой метод. В принципе там простой код, но если будут вопросы, буду рад ответить.